# Executing procedural queries in perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a query like this

```
set @valid_total:=0;
set @invalid_total:=0;
select week as weekno, measured_week,project_id as project, 
role_category_id as role_category,
valid_count,valid_tickets,
(@valid_total := @valid_total + valid_count) as valid_total, 
invalid_count,invalid_tickets, 
(@invalid_total := @invalid_total + invalid_count) as invalid_total
from metric_fault_bug_project 
where measured_week = yearweek(curdate())
and role_category_id = 1 and project_id = 11;
```

it executes fine in heidi (MySQL client) but when it comes to perl, it gives me this error

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the m
anual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ':=0;
                                set :=0;
                                select week as weekno, measured_week,project_id
as project' at line 1 at D:\Mx\scripts\test.pl line 35.
Can't execute SQL statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the man
ual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use ne
ar ':=0;
                                set :=0;
                                select week as weekno, measured_week,project_id
as project' at line 1
```

The problem seem to be in the `set @valid_total := 0;` line.

I am fairly new to Perl. Can anyone help?

this is the complete perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#use lib '/x01/home/kalpag/libs';


use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sid = 'issues';
my $user = 'root';
my $passwd = 'kalpa';
my $connection = "DBI:mysql:database=$sid;host=localhost";


my $dbhh = DBI->connect( $connection, $user, $passwd) ||
            die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";


my $sql_query = 'set @valid_total:=0;
         set @invalid_total:=0;
         select week as weekno, measured_week,project_id, 
                 role_category_id as role_category,
         valid_count,valid_tickets,
             (@valid_total := @valid_total + valid_count) as valid_total, 
                 invalid_count,invalid_tickets, 
         (@invalid_total := @invalid_total + invalid_count) as invalid_total
         from metric_fault_bug_project 
         where measured_week = yearweek(curdate())
         and role_category_id = 1 and project_id = 11';

 my $sth = $dbhh->prepare($sql_query) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement:     $DBI::errstr\n";

 $sth->execute() or die "Can't execute SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

while ( my @memory = $sth->fetchrow() )
{
            print "@memory \n";
}
```

Comment: I suspect it might be related to the @ sign. It appears to have lost the variable name. Have you tried escaping the @ signs?

Comment: thanks soz, yes i have tried using \@variable_name . but it does not work :(

Comment: Make sure you are using single quotes around your query. Using double quotes will cause Perl to try and use variable interpolation for anything with the @ or $ sigils.

Comment: i've tried using single quotes instead of double quotes. but to no avail. problem still stays.
anyways thanx  Unixmonkey

Comment: You really should include your perl code in your perl question. The answers you get now will be guesses.

Comment: @TLP i have posted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always use strict and warnings. if you don't have a variable @valid_total, warnings would then warn you

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @valid_total in string
```

and strict would even die.

In double quoted strings you must escape @ signs:

```
"set \@valid_total:=0;"
```

and if you don't need interpolation at all, better use single quotes.

edit: after I can see the perl code:

rather then doing

```
my $sql_query = 'set @valid_total:=0;
         set @invalid_total:=0;
...';
 my $sth = $dbhh->prepare($sql_query)
```

you should do:

```
my $sql_query = 'set @valid_total:=0';
my $sth = $dbhh->prepare($sql_query);
$sth->execute;
$sth->finish;

$sql_query = 'set @invalid_total:=0'
$sth = $dbhh->prepare($sql_query);
$sth->execute;
$sth->finish;
...
```

you cannot execute more than one statement in one query.

Comment: I can't believe you are getting the same error now. I guess now you are getting a different error because you are trying to use several statements in one query. You have to execute those statements all in single queries.

Comment: No, I don't mean do instead of prepare. I mean split your sql up into single queries and prepare and execute them one after another.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a double quoted string for your query string, in which case perl looks for the variables `@valid_total` and `@invalid_total`. This would imply that you are not using

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Because otherwise you would already know the error. The result is that perl replaces the variables with nothing, which is reflected in your error.

What you need to do is single quote the string:

```
my $query = 'set @valid_total:=0;
set @invalid_total:=0;
select week as weekno, measured_week,project_id as project, 
role_category_id as role_category,
valid_count,valid_tickets,
(@valid_total := @valid_total + valid_count) as valid_total, 
invalid_count,invalid_tickets, 
(@invalid_total := @invalid_total + invalid_count) as invalid_total
from metric_fault_bug_project 
where measured_week = yearweek(curdate())
and role_category_id = 1 and project_id = 11';
```

Comment: Thanks TLP, but i am using exactly what you have posted here. but it gives me error. it didn't help

Comment: @KalpaG In that case, I can't help you unless you post the relevant perl code.

Comment: Looking at your error, it says `set :=0`, which is typical of perl trying to interpolate an empty array into a string. I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Try `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $sql_query;` and see what is contained in your query.

Comment: `$VAR1 = "set \@valid_total:=0;\n\t\t\t\t\tset \@invalid_total:=0;\n\t\t\t\t\tsel
ect week as weekno, measured_week,project_id, \n\t\t\t\t\trole_category_id as ro
le_category,\n\t\t\t\t\tvalid_count,valid_tickets,\n\t\t\t\t\t(\@valid_total :=
\@valid_total + valid_count) as valid_total, \n\t\t\t\t\tinvalid_count,invalid_t
ickets, \n\t\t\t\t\t(\@invalid_total := \@invalid_total + invalid_count) as inva
lid_total\n\t\t\t\t\tfrom metric_fault_bug_project \n\t\t\t\t\twhere measured_we
ek = yearweek(curdate())\n\t\t\t\t\tand role_category_id = 1 and project_id = 11
";`

Comment: Looks like it should. Except possibly that you are missing a semi-colon at the end of your mysql query, but perhaps that is not required.